# Freeform Pro Form with Submission Progress

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, javascript

I have a freeform pro form that is using a piece of javascript to provide a progress indicator once a form is submitted. Idea is seen here: http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/

However, with this script enabled, the form will not submit. When I comment out the js, the form submits fine. I cannot figure out what I need to edit in the script to play nice with Freeform. Code is as follows:

```
function initProgressBtn(){
    jQuery('.form').each(function() {
        var form = jQuery(this);
        var sendBtn = form.find('.progress-button');
        var ajaxBusy = false;

        new ProgressButton( sendBtn.get(0), {
            callback : function( instance ) {
                var progress = 0,
                interval = setInterval( function() {
                    progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
                    instance._setProgress( progress );

                    if( progress === 1 ) {
                        instance._stop(1);
                        clearInterval( interval );
                    }
                }, 200 );
                form.trigger('startProgress');
            }
        });

        function onSendForm(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!ajaxBusy) {
                ajaxBusy = true;

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function() {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        form.on('submit startProgress', onSendForm);
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by adding the redirect url directly in the javascript:

```
success: function() {
window.location.href = "redirected-page.html";
}
```

Comment: Glad you got this sorted and reported back; you should accept your own answer so this question will not appear as "unanswered".